# how to keep session value in page that open twice in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, session-variables

I have a website . In homepage.aspx I use session["YID"] to send a value to fillparameter.aspx page. for going to fillparameter.aspx page, I use window.open(). Then I can open more than one page. 
In fillparameter.aspx I use a variable to get session. If I open second fillparameter.aspx page, in first fillparameter.aspx page session changed. 
Also I cant not use querystring.
How can I keep Last value of session in first fillparameter.aspx.
please help

Comment: I should say when I reload First fillparameter.aspx , session have changed